# How to use the AdvBandedGridView as a detail level in a GridControl

Tags: devexpress, master-detail, gridcontrol

I want to design a Master-Detail Grid view like that in the following Link:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument562

However, I want to use the AdvBandedGridView type as one of the details views, but I dont know how to fill its data.

I have found that the AdvBandedGridView  type is always the 'Main View' in all examples , but in my case I want it to be one of the inside ddetails.

How could I doing so,
Thanks so much in advance.
Best regards,
Aya.

Answer (score 0):

There is excelent article: [How to: Bind GridControl to Database and Implement Master-Detail Mode at Design Time](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2163). I believe it covers all possible aspects of your question.

Please also read the following article for additional details: [Master-Detail Relationships](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3473)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, but as I mentioned, my main problem is to deal with the AdvBandedGridView type, since it has a mixed bands, and I have a problem in filling its columns if it is one of the detail levels of other grid view.

Comment: @AyaZoghby There is no significant differences in GridView or AdvBandedGridView binding and customization. Thus it is not quite clear to me what the exactly you've tried and where you run into a problem. Please update your question with concrete details (datasource type/columns/bands etc.)

Comment: Alright, I used an ArrayList as the datasource of the MainView. This ArrayList contains other nested Lists that I used to fill the columns of the AdvBandedGridView . However I get a result differes from what I designed, despite I matched the FildName property with the properties names. and I dont know how to bind it correctly.

Comment: @AyaZoghby Would you please provide me with a sample code for your datasource (ArrayList and it's nested lists)?